# Google Admob always shows test adds on emulator even if the application is download and installed from the play store

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

I am trying to get real live ads on android studio emulator. I have read that admob displays test ads on the emulators but i am looking for a way if somehow i can get real ads on emulator.

I have tried installing application from the playstore. The application works but i always get test add.

I would like to get live ads on emulator by installing apps from play store.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never be able to get real ads on Android emulator as it is automatically configured as a test device.

As mentioned here:

[Test Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

> Android emulators are automatically configured as test devices.

Now, there's not much I could find about why they're automatically configured as test device, but that seems a good way to remove fake ad impressions from emulators.

If you were able to create 10000 emulators and configure them to run and use your app, get real ad impressions, and make fake clicks, wouldn't that mean fake traffic? Why do you even want to see real ads on emulator? Emulators are mostly for testing purposes only, and nobody uses them to do real tasks. Except, if you make your own ad network which will serve ads even on emulators(devices with no unique identifiers like IMEI number, etc).

And, even if you manage to make an ad network which will show real ads on emulators, get ready to get doomed, because people will just use your ad network, create 1000 emulators, and start getting that free ad money you're distributing!

Comment: with due respect i have been able to configure my emulator to get live ads on it i figured it out after a week i asked this question just got busy to reply back. Although it was never my intention to get fake clicks through it. Yes you are right that emulators are blocked for generating fraudulent traffic on the apps.

Comment: How were you able to configure emulator to get live ads? Your account will get blocked if you tried doing that.

Comment: Apparently there are some values in android's image that separates the emulators from an actual device. I unpacked the android system image changed those values repacked the changed image and replaced the image files with the original one and it worked. It started showing me real ads and tests ads watermark thingy is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the account blocking advise i don't have an ad account was just working on a solution for my company. We are market intelligence and compliance specialists. We give ad tracking services to our clients by scanning ads randomly over the internet in different regions.